# Android room UPSERT not working as expected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, upsert

I followed the documentation of android room `UPSERT` to implement a
simple block of code to upsert my entities.
Unfortunately it is not working as expected (for me).

The documentation example: [click here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/Upsert)
*Please read the example part*

So I added a `Playlist` entity, a `Dao`, the POJO `NameAndDescription` and the method
in the dao to upsert a playlist.

```kotlin
@Entity(
    tableName = "Playlist",
)
data class Playlist (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val playlistId: Long,
    val name: String,
    val description: String?,
    // ...
)
```

```kotlin
@Dao
interface PlayListDao {
    @Upsert(entity = Playlist::class)
    suspend fun upsertNewPlaylist(nameDescription: NameAndDescription)
}
```

```kotlin
data class NameAndDescription (
    val name: String,
    val description: String
)
```

And this is **exactly** how it is done in the documentation.

I was curious how `UPSERT` would work with using `NameAndDescription` which contains no constrained member of `PlaylistEntity`,
but okay, I will give it a try.

After inserting multiple values into the database on a button click...

```kotlin
var index = 0   
viewModelScope.launch {
  val name = "myName"
  val desc = "myDesc_" + index++            
  playlistDao.upsertNewPlaylist(NameAndDescription(name, desc))
}
```

.. I end up, as I expected, with multiple rows in the table.

```
myName, myDesc_0
myName, myDesc_1
myName, myDesc_2
```

So as I expected, without a primary key in my data object, it has no chance to update
the entities description.
But the docu example is exactly written like that.

**Q1**: Is the docu just wrong?

So I checked the generated `PlaylistDao_Impl` and saw that it tries to do an
insert and catches the `SQLiteConstraintException` and does an update in the `catch` block.

Cool, I think to myself. Let's add a constraint.

```kotlin
@Entity(
    tableName = "Playlist",
    indices = [Index(value = ["name"], unique = true)]
)
```

And I do the same thing, with upserting again, hoping that the constraint will
make upsert using this to update my row on the second button click.
But now? Wow...it **throws** an `SQLiteConstraintException` to me and the app crashes.
The fuc*?

So I dived deeper into the `PlaylistDao_Impl`, which is using an
`__upsertionAdapterOfNameAndDescriptionAsPlaylist` which does the following:

```kotlin
//...try insert
} catch (ex: SQLiteConstraintException) {
  checkUniquenessException(ex)
  updateAdapter.handle(entity)
}
```

And it turns out, `checkUniquenessException(ex)` will re-throw the exception,
if it is not due to a primary key constraint.

So in fact...I **do need to know the primary** in order to make an upsert.

**Q2**: Is this statement correct? And why on earth is the docu wrong? Or am I missing something here?

For me, this upsert feature doesn't bring any new advantages over using an
`INSERT` with ignore and an `UPDATE`, but on the downside **I need to know the primary key**, which is actually a step back from what I had before.

Could somebody please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doco says:-

> The implementation of the method will insert its parameters into the database if it does not already exists **(checked by primary key)**. If it already exists, it will update its parameters in the database.

i.e. if the primary isn't supplied then it will be an insert, irrespective of the other values (to be updated).

You are probably getting confused by:-

> If the target entity contains a PrimaryKey that is auto generated, then the POJO class doesn't need an equal primary key field, otherwise primary keys must also be present in the POJO.

This read on it's own could be interpreted as

> If the target entity contains a PrimaryKey that is auto generated, then the POJO class doesn't need an equal primary key field, otherwise primary keys must also be present in the POJO ***to update***

- **bolded added**

**BUT that is NOT what is says**, it does not say what the result (insert or update) would be.

However, then it clarifies with the next sentence being:-

> If the primary key already exists, only the columns represented by the partial entity fields will be updated

As such without the primary key the success will be an insert.

Comment: +1 thank you. But regarding the example within the documentation - it is still confusing and in my opinion a bad example isn't it? It should be an example about upsert, but it always will insert, since the lack of the primary key. Or is it the same here, that I might just be confused, because english is not my mother tongue? I mean, I was expecting an insert in the way the example is written. But got confused because it should in my opinion be an example for upsert.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re the clue is s per **`upsertNewPlaylist`** and also *POJO types that will be interpreted as partial entities*. Like so much documentation nowadays it is just a clue, as if ink were worth more than gold.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: it has been fixed https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.6.0-beta01

---

It's a bug in Room, the exception should not be rethrown when there is a uniqueness constraint on an index... see: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243039555#comment4